# Add entries together based on key in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

As you can see I have a key called dateTime which holds dates. What I need to do is add all the entries together for each date and return the array. So I simply got one dateTime per date with all the entries of that day added together. I do not know the dateTime inputs ahead of time as I have a crawler that constantly inserts data into my database.

How would you go about doing that in the most efficient way? I imagine I would have to do a foreach loop and somehow check if the key value (dateTime) changes from the previous key value. And then create a brand new array that I return

An example of the array is as follows:

```
array (size=130)


 0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-01' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '225' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-01' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '218' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-01' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '217' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-01' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '225' (length=3)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-02' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '231' (length=3)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-02' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '220' (length=3)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-03' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '223' (length=3)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-03' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '237' (length=3)
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-03' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '220' (length=3)
```

So it returns an array like this

```
array (size=130)

  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-01' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '660' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-02' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '451' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'dateTime' => string '2015-09-03' (length=10)
      'entries' => string '680' (length=3)
```

*Edit* With the help of you guys, I ended up doing the following to get the right format.

```
function prepareArrayForGraphDates($array){
$results = [];
$finalResult = [];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (!isset($results[$value['dateTime']])) {
        $results[$value['dateTime']] = 0;
    }
    $results[$value['dateTime']] += $value['entries'];    
}
$keyNames = array_keys($results);
for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($results); $x++) {
    $finalResult[$x]['dateTime'] = $keyNames[$x];
   $finalResult[$x]['entries'] = $results[$keyNames[$x]];
}
return $finalResult;
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: The question is the OP wants to sum the value `entries` per date.

Comment: Yeah. Maybe I wasn't specific enough. I have just edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that array keys are unique...

```
$results = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (!isset($results[$value['dateTime']])) {
        $results[$value['dateTime']] = 0;
    }
    $results[$value['dateTime']] += $value['entries'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array like a set or a dictionary, using the date as the key.

```
$data = [
  [
    'datetime'=>'2015-09-02',
    'entries' => 220
  ]
  // ... other entries snipped ...
];

$results = [];
foreach ($data as $date => $entry) 
{
      // if the date has already been recorded with an initial value, add to it
      if (array_key_exists($date, $results) {
          $results[$date] += $entry
      } else {
          // the date is new; add it to the results and set its initial value
          $results[$date] = $entry;
      }

}
```